# text-align: right; only for placeholder?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

how can active `text-align: right;` only for placeholder?

```
<input type="text" name="airline_search" style="direction: ltr;  border: none;" placeholder="ارلاین">
```

i want use of `direction: ltr;` for text(that typed to inpute), and `text-align: right;` for placeholder.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
/* webkit solution */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { text-align:right; }
/* mozilla solution */
input:-moz-placeholder { text-align:right; }
```

Comment: for chrome and opera, what is it?

Comment: AFAIK, not supported. Try this Jquery fix: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: I constantly receive notifications of new upvotes on this answer. Is this quirk still relevant in 2017?

Comment: Still gets an upvote in 2019 because it was an excellent answer. So does the comment by @elipoultorak because it's the right answer going forward. ❤

Comment: It seems to be working now in chrome input::placeholder { text-align: right }

Comment: And according to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) adding:
`::placeholder { text-align: right; }`

Answer (score 26):

Or try it with a `:focus` event:

```
input[type='text']{
text-align:right;
}

input[type='text']:focus{
text-align:left;
}
```

This way, any placeholder even hard-coded will be held on right, and any text you type when focused will be on right.
On the other hand, when you lose the focus, the alignement becomes right again.

Comment: This is a good method. But it will also float your text back in the center after the focus has changed.

Comment: this inspired me to try `input[type='text']:empty{text-align:right;}`.  The placeholder stays at the right until text is entered... :-)  but unfortunately so does the text cursor, which is sure to confuse. :-(

Answer (score 22):

It's better to set CSS style for placeholder as @Hnatt mentioned. I used it with setting direction and the complete list of the selector for known browsers as below:

```
::-webKit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    direction: rtl;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    direction: rtl;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ but I'm not sure about working */
    direction: rtl;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 19):

As of year 2020, CSS selector `::placeholder` is supported in all major browsers except Internet Explorer:

```css
input::placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Edge requires vendor prefix:

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Sources: [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_placeholder), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)

Comment: This should have been on top! Updated

Answer (score 4):

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The post of Villi Katrih is right, but miss in the direction. You should use:

direction: rtl;
text-align: left;

'direction' affects the placeholder text placement, while 'text-align' affects to the content of the input.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Sample" style="direction: rtl; text-align: left;">
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

using inline-jquery

```
onkeyup="if($(this).val()==''){ $(this).css({'text-align':'right'})} else{ $(this).css({'text-align':'left'})}"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq5ep/)

Answer (score 1):

[`::placeholder` pseudo-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#placeholder-pseudo) is still a working draft and it has a very limited number of supported CSS properties.

> All properties that apply to the ::first-line pseudo-element also apply to the ::placeholder pseudo-element.

No additional Properties are stated, but it has been noted people would like `text-align` to be supported.

So from the fairly small list of supported properties [(found here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line), the only correct way you could achieve this would be if your placeholder text was only one word long. 
This would allow you to take advantage of the supported `word-spacing` property by prefixing a  character and then hide it.

This probably doesn't work because it doesn't use browser prefixes.

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff!important;
}
input::placholder {
  word-spacing: 155px;
}
input::placholder:first-letter {
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="airline_search" style="direction: ltr;  border: none;" placeholder="- ارلاین">
```

This should work

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff!important;
}
input::placholder {
  word-spacing: 155px;
}
input::placholder::first-letter {
  color: #fff!important;
}
/* browser support */

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  word-spacing: 155px;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
  word-spacing: 155px;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  word-spacing: 155px;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  word-spacing: 155px;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder::first-letter {
  color: #fff!important;
}
input:-moz-placeholder:first-letter {
  color: #fff!important;
}
input::-moz-placeholder::first-letter {
  color: #fff!important;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder::first-letter {
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="airline_search" style="direction: ltr;  border: none;" placeholder="- ارلاین">
```

But as browsers support thing they shouldn't and don't support thing they should you could just try this.

This isnt supposed to work .

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  text-align: right;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  text-align: right;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ but I'm not sure about working */
  text-align: right;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10 */
  text-align: right;
}
input::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="airline_search" style="direction: ltr;  border: none;" placeholder="ارلاین">
```

FYI `direction: ltr;` manages the cursor position and the flow of text, as a placeholder doesn't have a cursor or editable text it wont do anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
::placeholder {/* Firefox */
text-align: right;}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 text-align: right;}
 
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
text-align: right;}  </style>

<input  type="text" placeholder="تست">
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me (in Firefox), so I could display a `` (on the right) until the user starts typing (on the left).

Answer (score 0):

did you try add it in the style?

```
<input type="text" name="airline_search" style="direction: ltr; text-align: right;  border: none;" placeholder="ارلاین">
```

or just set an outside div like this:

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">
<input type="text" name="airline_search" style="text-align: right;  border: none;" placeholder="ارلاین">
</div>
```

should work.

Comment: i want use of 'direction: ltr;' for text, and 'text-align: right;' for placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.
By this You can use of input in real direction auto and enjoy of using correct rtl placeholder.

```js
//jQuery

(function($) {
 $.fn.dir_auto = function() {


  var selector  = '.inputs-nyn[dir="auto"]';
  var sclass    = "auto-nyn05";
  var ftime     = true;


  if ( $(selector).length ) {

   $(document).on("keyup", selector , function() {

    if( ftime || !$(this).val() ){
     if( !$(this).val() ){
      $(this).addClass(sclass);
      ftime = true;
     }
     else{
      $(this).removeClass(sclass);
      ftime = false;
     }
    }
   });

  } 
 };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.dir_auto();

});
```

```css
//css

body{
    direction: rtl;
}

.inputs-nyn.auto-nyn05[dir="auto"] {
    
    direction: rtl;
}

.inputs-nyn[dir="auto"]::placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->

<input class="inputs-nyn auto-nyn05" dir="auto" placeholder="ارلاین" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

input **placeholder** align :

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
```

input **text** align :

```
<input style="text-align: left;" />
```