# jQuery change placeholder text color

Tags: jquery, input, colors, placeholder

Is it possible to use "::-webkit-input-placeholder" with jQuery to set a color for the placeholder text?

Something like this:

```
$("input::-webkit-input-placeholder").css({"color" : "#b2cde0"});
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: Nice to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20886968/1830909

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can't really modify pseudo-selectors with JavaScript. You'll have to modify an existing a [`<style>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript).

If possible, make a class:

```
.your-class::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #b2cde0
}
```

And add it to the element:

```
 $('input').addClass('your-class');
```

Comment: I believe most of the time the point of styling placeholder text with jQuery would be dynamic colors.

Answer (score 3):

If you **don't have a stylesheet**, and want to inject CSS **dynamically** you can use the following:

```
$('body').append('<style>.my_class::placeholder{color:red}</style>')
```

Just use **my_class** and the **color** for the placeholder.

It's handy to have a general purpose function:

```
function change_placeholder_color(target_class, color_choice) {
    $("body").append("<style>" + target_class + "::placeholder{color:" +  color_choice + "}</style>")
}
```

**Usage**:

```
change_placeholder_color('.my_input', 'red')
```

Comment: In one line: `$('input').append('<style>.my_class::placeholder{color:red}</style>').addClass('my_class');`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this. It will inherit the color in input[type=text]:focus new color

```
.your-class ::placeholder{ color: inherit;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of dynamically setting pseudo-element styles using jQuery – it's a matter of creating a `<style>` element, setting its text content to the desired style declarations, and appending it to the document.

Here is a simple single-page example:

```
<!doctype html>                                                                                                                                                                 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Pseudo-element Styles</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script> 
$(document).ready(function() {                      
    createStyles();
    $('#slider-font-size').on('change', createStyles);

    function createStyles() {
        // remove previous styles
        $('#ph-styles').remove();

        // create a new <style> element, set its ID
        var $style = $('<style>').attr('id', 'ph-styles');

        // get the value of the font-size control
        var fontSize = parseInt($('#slider-font-size').val(), 10);

        // create the style string: it's the text node
        // of our <style> element
        $style.text(
            '::placeholder { ' +
                'font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;' +
                'font-size: ' + fontSize + 'px;' +
            '}');

        // append it to the <head> of our document
        $style.appendTo('head');
    }   
});     
        </script>
    </head>      

    <body>       
        <form>
            <!-- uses the ::placeholder pseudo-element style in modern Chrome/Firefox -->   
            <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text..."><br>

            <!-- add a bit of dynamism: set the placeholder font size -->
            <input id="slider-font-size" type="range" min="10" max="24">
        </form>
    </body>      
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using MaterializeCSS; I used Jquery to update CSS for input fields like this

```
  $(".input-field").css("color", themeColor);
  $(".input-field>.material-icons").css("color", themeColor);
  $(".input-field>label").css("color", themeColor);
```

See Result:

https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/EXoPRq?editors=1000

Comment: the person instructed that he is looking to change the placeholder styling not the regular text,