# changing placeholder text font and color with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I have an input tag of the following form

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name">
```

First I check that the field is not empty using jquery

```
 $("#submitreg").click(function(e){
     if ($.trim($("#firstname").val())=='')
         {
             $("#firstname").attr('placeholder',"first name can't be empty");
             e.preventDefault();
         }
 });
```

Now if the input field is empty, I change the placeholder to "first name can't be empty". Is it also possible to change the placeholder color to red and make the font 85% using jquery.

Thanks

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: how to change the placeholder color to red and make the font of the placeholder 85% using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery change placeholder text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967250/jquery-change-placeholder-text-color)

Comment: @GokulSandeep these solutions don't work

Comment: Is your idea that if the textbox is empty then the placeholder will be red and the font is 85%?

Comment: nope. I currently have a placeholder called first name. When I submit form I check if the text area is empty. if it empty I want to change the place holder to  "first name cant be empty" and change its color to red and make its font small to notify user that the first name field is empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
$('#form-id').submit(function(e) { //Add event listener on form and not on btn click
  if ($('#firstname').val().trim() === '') { //Check if empty string
    $("#firstname").attr('placeholder', "first name can't be empty"); //Change attribute
    $("#firstname").val(''); //Remove the value so that youll see the new attribute
    $("#firstname").addClass('red'); //Add a class so that placeholder will be red.
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the form on sending
  }
});
```

```css
.red::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
   color: red;
   opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

.red:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color: red;
}

.red::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form-id'>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks how to make sure that is supported by all browsers

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what are you looking for

This css will not support for all browsers

[-webkit-input-placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-input-placeholder), [::placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder), [::-moz-placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder), [:-ms-input-placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-ms-input-placeholder) prefer `Browser compatibility` in those links

```js
$("#submitreg").click(function(e){
     $("#firstname").val($.trim($("#firstname").val()));
     if ($.trim($("#firstname").val())=='')
         {
             $("#firstname").attr('placeholder',"first name can't be empty");
             $("#firstname").addClass('your-class');
             e.preventDefault();
         } else {
              $("#firstname").removeClass('your-class');
         }
         
 });
```

```css
.your-class:-moz-placeholder{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.your-class::placeholder{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.your-class:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.your-class::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}


input {
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name" />

<button type="submit" id="submitreg">Submit</button>
```

Comment: thats exactly what I am looking for. my question is this supported by all browsers

Comment: See my edit post. I already attached the browser support for each css  `pseudo-class`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .your-class1::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: red
    }
    .your-class2::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: black
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          //Attach change event to textbox
          $("#textbox1").change(function() {
              //Check if value is empty or not
              if ($(this).val() == "") {
                  //if empty then assign the border
                  $("#textbox1").addClass('your-class1');
             }
            else
            {
              $("#textbox1").addClass('your-class2');
            }
          });
        });  

        function validatetextbox()
        {
          var txtval = $("#textbox1").val();
          //Check if value is empty or not
          if (txtval == "") {
               //if empty then assign the border
              $("#textbox1").addClass('your-class1');

          }
          else
         {
             $("#textbox1").addClass('your-class2');
         }
        }
      </script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="textbox1" placeholder="Placeholder text...">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validatetextbox()">
    </body>
    </html>
```