# How to change input element placeholder's color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

It is possible to assign the text:

```
inputElement.placehoder="my placeholder";
```

But how to adjust placeholder's color or opacity (without creating css selectors) ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder  afaik, you have to make a class.  Inline styles only affect the element they are on, and children if their properties are inherited

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update placeholder color using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749402/how-to-update-placeholder-color-using-javascript)

Comment: There is another StackOverflow thread fixes it using JQuery.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967250/jquery-change-placeholder-text-color Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class say, `custom-placeholder` attached to a predefined `::placeholder` selector to your css and then use JavaScript to add it to your element like this:

```
.custom-placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.custom-placeholder:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.custom-placeholder::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above:

```js
document.getElementById("input").classList.add("custom-placeholder");
```

```css
.custom-placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.custom-placeholder:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.custom-placeholder::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="hello world" />
<input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="this would not be affected" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define classes for the different appearances you want and then apply those classes through your JS.

See the answer to this question to do that: [jQuery change placeholder text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967250/jquery-change-placeholder-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can't; only the pseudo-element [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) in CSS can effect the color

At best, you can apply this styling to a class / id, and then use JavaScript to add that class to your element

```css
::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="I should be blue" />
```