# HTML change placeholder direction

Tags: html, css

how to in styled `input` tag placeholder extends that parent style and i want to have `right direction` in `left` styled input.

for example this is my input:

```
<input type="password" style='direction:ltr;text-align:left;' id="password" placeholder="password">
```

placeholder text-align is left now. how to use `direction:rtl` for that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think this can help you.

```
input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyjED)

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs: (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

> In situations where the control's content has one directionality but
>   the placeholder needs to have a different directionality, Unicode's
>   bidirectional-algorithm formatting characters can be used in the
>   attribute value:

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it on focus:

```
input[type='text']{
text-align:right;
}

input[type='text']:focus{
text-align:left;
}
```

Although this is not exactly what you asked, it seems better to me since many browsers such as Firefox 3 and IE 8, 9 don't support changing the placeholders' style. [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730012/2550529)