# How to append data to user input when saving to the database?

Tags: php, jquery, css, email, registration

I would like to create a registration form like [Gmail](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/?pc=topnav-about-en).

I know how to create a basic form with some basic php coding for validate and connecting it to the MySQL database. But I want to have the Gmail-like username features where users can register for an email account without filling in `"@domain.com"`.

Here is an image: https://flic.kr/p/nxxUqt

[image: Screenshot]

Basically, users do not have to type the "@gmail.com" when registering but the "@gmail.com" will be INSERT into the MySQL database.

**HERE IS MY CODING**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    //form data
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $name2 = strip_tags($_POST['name2']);
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['password2']);
    $email2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
    $address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);
    $address2 = strip_tags($_POST['address2']);
    $address3 = strip_tags($_POST['address3']);
    $address4 = strip_tags($_POST['address4']);
    $error = array();
    if ($submit) {
        //open database
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Error");
        //select database
        mysql_select_db("logindb") or die("Selection Error");
        //namecheck
        $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' OR email='{$email}'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
        if ($count!=0) {
            $error[] = "<div style='border:thin solid red'><span style='color:red'><b>ID or Display Name already taken</b></span></div>";
        }
        //check for existance
        if($name&&$name2&&$username&&$email&&$password&&$password2&&$email2&&$address&&$address2&&$address3&&$address4) {
            //encrypt password
            $password = md5 ($password);
            $password2 = md5 ($password2);
            if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) {
                $error[] = "<div style='border:thin solid red'><span style='color:red'>Password does not match</span></div>";
            }
            if(isset($error)&&!empty($error)) {
                implode($error);
            }
            else
            {
                //Registering to database
                $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$name2','$username','$email','$password','$password2','$email2','$address','$address2','$address3','$address4')");
                die ("<p>You have been registered! <br><a href='Login.php'>Click here to return to Login</a></p>");     
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

hi guys thanks for helping out now i have validation issues, when i want to validate my username the email validation come out together with the username ones
**HERE IS MY VALIDATION CODING**

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("logindb");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'].='@domain.com');
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' OR email='{$email}'");
$check = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($username==NULL) {
    echo "";
}
else
{
    if(strlen($username)<5) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>Please enter 5 to 25 characters</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        if($check==0) {
        }
        else
        {
            if($check==1) {
                echo "<span style='color:red'>Display Name taken. Try another?</span>";
            }
        }
    }
}
if($email==NULL) {
    echo "";
}
else
{
    if(strlen($email)<5||strlen($email)>30) {
        echo "Please enter 5 to 30 characters";
    }
    else
    {
        if($check==0) {
        }
        else
        {
            if($check==1) {
            echo "Email Taken";
            }
        }
    }
}
if($password==NULL) {
    echo "";
}
else
{
    if(strlen($password)<6) {
        echo "<ul><li><span style='color:red'>Please enter at least 6 characters</span></li>";
    }
    if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$password)) {
        echo "<li><span style='color:red'>Please enter at least 1 upper case characters</span></li>";
    }
    if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
        echo "<li><span style='color:red'>Please enter at least 1 number</span></li>";
    }
    if(!preg_match("#[\W]+#",$password)) {
        echo "<li><span style='color:red'>Please enter at least 1 symbol</span></li></ul>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure `php` is not involved here.

Comment: I suspect that's just a div that uses absolute or relative positioning to place it on top of the input box, and then the input box uses padding to prevent the cursor from going underneath the overlay. If you explore it using your browser's element inspector, you should be able to see its CSS features.

Comment: then how can i create this similar feature and inserting it into database can you help me

Comment: What in particular are you stuck on? If the answer is "all of it" then the question is too broad, and you need to break it down into pieces.

Comment: basicly what I get out of this question is that he want us to give a code to get this done...

Comment: @halfer i have updated the question please have a look thanks

Comment: The html place-holder .. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729837/text-align-right-only-for-placeholder .. you can append @gmail.com fixed from backend

Comment: Right, so this is about the backend, and not about the form at all. I've edited your question to make that clear. Can we now see your code that you use to save data into your database? It seems that it would just be a case of appending a string to a column value when you do your `INSERT`.

Comment: @halfer i have added the coding

Comment: Nice code, it smells SQL injections everywhere.

Comment: Something like `$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']) . '@example.com';`? However, don't use `strip_tags` - at the very least switch to `mysql_real_escape_string`, so you are protected from SQL injection.

Comment: @halfer ok thanks i worked but now i have validation issue

Comment: Your new `$email` line is wrong - use `.` rather than `.=`. It's worth taking a moment when copying code examples to see what they actually do, as this is the path to understanding how your code works. (Also, if you have a "validation issue", it helps greatly if you can explain what it actually is - in most cases we cannot help otherwise).

Comment: @halfer i have edited the question a little-bit but may not seem understandable. In the validation page i think the $check is the problem can you help me check if it is?

Comment: Have you tried using `echo` to see if it is the value you expect?

Comment: @halfer where should i echo it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to encapsulate your `input` control inside a container (e.g. a `span`). Inside this span you also add another element (e.g. anorther span) with absolute positioning.

Don't forget to add `padding` to your `input` so that when users write their usernames, then usernames does not overlap the `@domain` stuff.

So my HTML is:

```
<span class="placeholder"><label>@domain</label><input type="text" name="username"/></span>
```

while my CSS is:

```
 .placeholder {
     position:relative;
 }
 .placeholder label{
     position:absolute;
     right:0;
     margin-right:0.4em;
     color:#aaa;
 }
 .placeholder input{
     padding-right:5em;
 }
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vjt6E/

---

Then in your `PHP` code, you must add this value.

So, if your sending your data through a `POST` method you add at the beggining of your PHP code:

```
<?php
    $_POST['username'].='@domain'

... rest of your code here ...
```

If your are sending using a GET request then do:

```
<?php
    $_GET['username'].='@domain'

... rest of your code here ...
```

Comment: @antonio-ragagin i have updated the question please have a look thank you

Comment: +1 for the effort, but it's worth not responding to questions until they are specific - otherwise you might end up answering the wrong thing.

Comment: @halfer, have you checked my `PHP` snippets? I think they responds the the question.

Comment: Yes, indeed - my point was that I don't think the CSS was needed at all. Or, if it was, the OP was stuck on so many things it should have been closed as too broad; in my view, answerers should save their effort until it is clear what effort is needed `:)`.

Comment: (Btw, I don't recommend you modify the superglobals directly, as you may need to access to 'real' values in the same request. It's better to read the value into a variable, and then to do escaping and appending to that copy).