# How do I move the search icon (&#128269;) placeholder to the right side of the search input box using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I move the search icon () placeholder to the right side of the search input box using CSS? I've tried to select it by using ::placeholder, but it still didn't work.

Here's my code:

```css
/*
Form Styles
------------------------------*/
h1 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8%;
}   
#name,
#email,
#password,
#phone {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
#search {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 305px;
}
button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background: lightblue;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-left: 268px;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <h1>Our Form</h1>
        <form action="success.html" method="get">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="jen"><br>
            <label for="search">Search</label>
            <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="&#128269;"><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            
        </form>

    </main>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729837/text-align-right-only-for-placeholder/20886968 so the answer `input::placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}` did not work? Seems to work in chrome when I tested it in your code.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks for the help.